# Referencing Buttons Created Dynamically to a Corresponding Lable Kivy Python

Tags: python, button, reference, kivy

Some background:
One of my screens in my app shows an angle value in degrees-minutes-seconds. Those values are MDLabels created as you enter the screen and the values are depended on the MDTextFields values given by the user in the previous screen. The number of angles is depended on the first screen in which the user is been asked how many points are there. So that if there are 5 points, there will be 5 angles with each having a different degrees-minutes-seconds text inputs. Each angle is a list with 3 values (degrees, minutes and seconds) and each angle is stored in a list called angles. So it's a 2-D list situation which helps me with calculations.

Now to the question:
In this screen my goal is to let the user adjust the angles by pressing the + and - buttons so that each press will increase/decrease the seconds value by one.
the problem I have is referencing the buttons to the angle - so that if I press the + button of the second angle, for example, it will only add a second to the second angle.
I just don't know how to write the plus()/minus() methods in such a way.

```
class AngleAdjustment(Screen):
def on_enter(self, *args):
    self.adj_angle_widgets = []
    self.adj_angles_widgets = []
    self.minus_buttons = []
    self.plus_buttons = []
    angle_number = 0
    for angle in angles:
        angle_number += 1
        self.angle_to_adjust_title = MDLabel(text="Angle " + str(angle_number), font_size=20, halign="center") #Adds title to each angle
        self.angle_adjustment_gridlayout = MDGridLayout(cols=5, spacing="10dp", padding="10dp", adaptive_height=True) # Puts everything and angle needs within a gridlayout
        self.minus_button = MDIconButton(icon="minus-circle", user_font_size="40sp")
        self.degrees_to_adjust = MDLabel(text=str(angle[0]), halign="center") # Gets user input from previous screen
        self.minutes_to_adjust = MDLabel(text=str(angle[1]), halign="center") # Gets user input from previous screen
        self.seconds_to_adjust = MDLabel(text=str(angle[2]), halign="center") # Gets user input from previous screen
        self.plus_button = MDIconButton(icon="plus-circle", user_font_size="40sp")

        self.adj_angle_widgets = [int(self.degrees_to_adjust.text),
                                  int(self.minutes_to_adjust.text),
                                  int(self.seconds_to_adjust.text)]

        self.adj_angles_widgets.append(self.adj_angle_widgets)

        self.minus_buttons.append(self.minus_button)
        self.plus_buttons.append(self.plus_button)

        self.angle_adjustment_gridlayout.add_widget(self.minus_button)
        self.angle_adjustment_gridlayout.add_widget(self.degrees_to_adjust)
        self.angle_adjustment_gridlayout.add_widget(self.minutes_to_adjust)
        self.angle_adjustment_gridlayout.add_widget(self.seconds_to_adjust)
        self.angle_adjustment_gridlayout.add_widget(self.plus_button)

        self.ids.angle_adjustment.add_widget(self.angle_to_adjust_title) # Adding the widgets to the MDBoxLayout written in the KV file
        self.ids.angle_adjustment.add_widget(self.angle_adjustment_gridlayout) # Adding the widgets to the MDBoxLayout written in the KV file

        self.minus_button.bind(on_press=self.minus) # Binding the minus button
        self.plus_button.bind(on_press=self.plus) # Binding the plus button
```

[user input angle values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sL0n.png) [user adjust angle values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZoxh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to figure this out, for anyone's reference. I was not aware of the button state option - had some good time reading the documentation:

```
    def minus(self, btn):
        for i in range(N):
            if self.minus_buttons[i].state == "down":
                print(f'minus button {i+1} is down')

    def plus(self, btn):
        for i in range(N):
            if self.plus_buttons[i].state == "down":
                print(f'plus button {i+1} is down')
```

From here on I can do calculations based on which ever button was clicked!